# Mechanism design in continuous time models

Tags: finance, finance-mathematics, market-microstructure, financial-engineering, game-theory

I am interested in mechanism design and information design. Is there any part of the literature in financial mathematics that is associated with them. I mean could we bring somehow these topics under the light of continuous time models? Do we have any references (papers, books, whatever)?

Comment: https://www.darrellduffie.com/uploads/pubs/AntillDuffieSep2020.pdf